# Scala - Regex for uncertain repetitive pattern

Tags: regex, scala

In Scala, I've a string inputs like

```
1. [[Country].[US]-[Country].[Canada]]
2. [[Country].[US]-[Country].[Canada]-[Country].[Mexico]]
3. [[Country].[US].[New York]-[Country].[US].[California]]
```

I need to extract following for above strings

```
1. [Country].[US], [Country].[Canada]
2. [Country].[US], [Country].[Canada], [Country].[Mexico]
3. [Country].[US].[New York], [Country].[US].[California]
```

They are random, separated by - (hyphen).

I need a regex that can match groups. I can make it work for static pattern, but don't know how to accommodate dynamic ones.

I can't split it with hyphen, as there can be another input containing negative integers, like

```
 [Rank].[-1]-[Rank].[1]-[Rank].[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply drop the first and last character and split by `"-"`:

```
def extractTokens(text: String) = text.drop(1).dropRight(1).split("-")

> extractTokens("[[Country].[US]-[Country].[Canada]]")
> Array([Country].[US], [Country].[Canada])

> extractTokens("[[Country].[US]-[Country].[Canada]-[Country].[Mexico]]")
> Array([Country].[US], [Country].[Canada], [Country].[Mexico])
```

Comment: Thank you Jean. But, my input may contain -ve numbers (edited). Also, I'm curious about how regex can be used for dynamic values.